# Detect if an iframe is loaded with JavaScript (including those that fail from Cross origin)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an url viewer in my webpage that uses iframes and I would like to detect when the iframe is loaded. I don't need to know if the iframe fails to load. What I want is knowing when it is really loaded.

I have tried with:

```
$(iframe).on('load', ...)
```

but it gets triggered even when the browser throws a "Refused to display ...":

```
// example
<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>).
```

so I thought I could check if the document is empty or not using iframe.contentDocument but it seems that it isn't always accessible:

```
// example with a youtube link
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-7EVT6IyFxk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think it is simply not possible.